# How to create a VirtualHost on Apache and "import" sites I already made?

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, virtual-host

I learnt I have to use Apache's `VirtualHosts` to correctly point different domains to different sites on my server.

Before I knew this, I already made 2 different wordpress sites, and they are in Apache's base `DocumentRoot` folder (`/var/www/html/site1` and `/var/www/html/site2`).

I'm currently visualizing and modifying them by accessing the `http://x.x.x.x/site1` address from my browser.

How can I create two separate `VirtualHost` for each?

How can I "migrate" my already made sites to a new `VirtualHost` without breaking the sites, and maintaining Wordpress linked to his dbs?

[More informations are on this question of mine](https://superuser.com/questions/1453807/pointing-domains-to-wordpress-site-hosted-on-vps)

Answer (score 1):

Create a <VirtualHost> as normal, then point its DocumentRoot setting to `/var/www/html/site1` and this will be served whenever you visit `http://yourdomain/`. There is no "importing".

What's important is that the website *itself* wouldn't have links pointing to the old URL. As the websites are built using WordPress, you need to tell WordPress about the new address:

- either before migrating – visit *Settings → General* and change the "WordPress Address" and "Site Address" fields to match the new (future) URLs.
- or after migrating – according to instructions at [WordPress.org Support: Changing The Site URL](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/).

Comment: I tried editing that Wordpress setting field before, without the VirtualHost and making my domain point to x.x.x.x/mysite , but it completely broke the website and I had to manually edit the wp-config files to get it back, the admin console was either gone. Will this not happen with virtualhosts configured? Can you explain me why it broke the website in the other case?

Comment: Also some guide I read stated something about editing also the /etc/hosts file, how is that involved?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "making my domain point to x.x.x.x/mysite"? Domains don't generally work that way.

Comment: I have a vps whos IP adress is "x.x.x.x", I put my site in /var/www/html/mysite/, so to view it from web I used myipaddress/mysite. Once i purchased a domain, I made it point to that address